# Able to persist data using entitymanager.persist() but unable to get using entitymanager.find() in spring hibernate application

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, persistence

This is my customer entity

```
@Entity
public class Customer
{
    @Id
    private String account_no;
    private String customer_name,father_name,gender, phone, email, aadhaar;     // phone no is varchar because I'll do validation in angular.
    private double salary;

    // one customer can have one loan. Relation is unidirectional
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="account_no")
    private Loan loan;

    public Customer() {}


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CustomerInfo [account_no=" + account_no + ", customer_name=" + customer_name + ", phone=" + phone
                + ", email=" + email + ", aadhaar=" + aadhaar + ", salary="
                + salary + ", loan=" + loan + "]";
    }
}
```

Now this is my Loan entity

```
@Entity
public class Loan
{

    @Id
    @Column(name="account_no")
    private String account_no;          // making this as foreign key will not allow any holder to take loan again.
    private String type;
    private String issue_date;
    private String last_payment;
    private double loan_amount;
    private double emi_amount;
    private int emi_balance;

    public Loan() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "LoanInfo [account_no=" + account_no + ", type=" + type + ", loan_amount=" + loan_amount
                + ", emi_amount=" + emi_amount + ", emi_balance=" + emi_balance + ", issue_date=" + issue_date + "]";
    }



}
```

Now the code of Dao layer
The findCustomer() function is returning null.
In dao findLoan() and addCustomer() is working fine.Even I've checked database , it is persisting data to database.
Database which I'm using is mysql and hibernate is used to implement the application. Spring mvc is used .

```
@Repository("bankDao")
@Transactional
public class BankDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;


    // It add customer details and loan details like emi while sanctioning any loan.
    public void addCustomer(Customer customer) throws RevokeLoanException
    {
        try {
            em.persist(customer);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            throw new RevokeLoanException();
        }
    }

    // for customer details
    public Customer findCustomer(String accNo) throws LoanNotFoundException{

        System.out.println(em.find(Customer.class, accNo));
        Customer customer=em.find(Customer.class, accNo);
        if(customer==null)
            throw new LoanNotFoundException();
        return customer;
    }

    // useful while paying emi
    public Loan findLoan(String acc_no) throws LoanNotFoundException{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Loan loan=em.find(Loan.class, acc_no);
        if(loan==null)
            throw new LoanNotFoundException();
        return loan;
    }
```

Problem arising in controller . Controller is not working in the specific way for id=2020-04-30T23:22:00.210

Api call =  http://localhost:8082/LoanBackEnd/loan/loanStatus/2020-04-30T23:22:00.210

```
@GetMapping("/loanStatus/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> loanStatus(@PathVariable String id) throws LoanNotFoundException{
        System.out.println(id+" which got");
        Map<String,String> response=bankService.loanStatus(id);

        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String,String>>(response,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

That print line is returning me 2020-04-30T23:22:00 in place of 2020-04-30T23:22:00.210

Comment: What type of column is the `account_no` in the database a VARCHAR or a CHAR?

Comment: @M. Deinum varchar

Comment: Then you either are querying with the wrong number (make sure the case is consistent!) and that there are no spaces in your account number when either querying or persisting it. (And really make sure it is a varchar!).

Comment: Yeah you're right. But I am not sure how is this happening.

Comment: New problem sir, just see my controller, don't know why it not taking full id .<br> See I have uploaded controller in the question.

Comment: Using a timeshare as id is a bad idea imho. You are loosing the last part as that is interpreted as an extension.